# Use react in vue 3 - possibilities and technical problems

Tags: reactjs, vue.js, vuejs3

I have a some situation in my current project when I must connect two technologies.
My project is build in `Vue 3 composition` api. I wand to add to then 3rd party SDK. Problem what I have is with SDK because right now support only react.

All widgets and components I can implement in `react`. At this stage of product is too late to move everything from `Vue` to `react`, and client want to have this SDK implemented in project.

My question is: is it possible to create one simple app in `react` which will be have implementation of SDK and put them into `Vue` component?
What about performance of this solution? Any one have similar problem? How to find best way to solve this?

I heard about `Veaury` but I never use that. Maybe this is good idea? How you thinking?

Comment: Probably yes, with react portal and vue teleport, but the maintainability will be horrible.

Comment: What is the 3rd party SDK? Could we see some docs? It's unlikely that it really is "just react", it's likely that they just have a react wrapper...

Comment: Can't say about Veaury, it totally depends on how it's implemented and maintained. You can always come up with your own bridge that respects the lifecycle of each framework in use, here's V2-V3 example https://stackoverflow.com/a/73547129/3731501 that can be rewritten for any combo of frameworks

Comment: @AKX is Webex SDK

Comment: @mcmac Right. Well, the Webex browser SDK is absolutely not react-specific: https://developer.webex.com/docs/sdks/browser#getting-started